# How to stop smooth div autoscroll after last image

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling, autoscroll

I am using Thomas Kahn jquery smooth div scroll. I would like to stop the autoscroll feature after the last image has shown. I am not a experienced web programmer. I tried to find a solution in the documentation but couldn't. Maybe somebody had the same problem as me and found a solution. Here is my webpage http://www.somersetsights.co.za/en/unser_haus.html. Thanks

Comment: `.stop(true, true)` use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution:

```
.stop(true, true)
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Thanks for you solution. Unfortunately I am not a experienced JS programmer. Could you please tell me where I have to insert this line of code) Thanks